# How to catch an Exception on Spring Bean start()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have a Spring Integration application where I use an IntegrationFlowContext to manage my integration flows. They need to be started, stopped and restarted dynamically through an exposed endpoint. My issue is how to catch an exception thrown when I run:

`integrationFlowContext.getRegistrationById(flowId).start()`

This can be any sort of exception, like file not found, bad queue name, bad websocket URL etc.

I have tried wrapping the code above in a try-catch block, but the Lifecycle call runs asynchronously, so the exception is not caught there.

### Edit

Below is an example flow that my be retried when an Exception is thrown:

```
@Configuration
class FlowConfig {
  @Value("${ws.url}")
  private String wsUrl;

  @Bean
  MessageChannel myWebSocketOutputChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
  }

  @Bean
  MessageChannel myWebSocketErrorChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
  }

  @Bean
  WebSocketClient standardWebSocketClient() {
    return new StandardWebSocketClient();
  }

  @Bean
  IntegrationWebSocketContainer myIntegrationWebSocketContainer(
      final WebSocketClient webSocketClient) throws IOException {
    return new ClientWebSocketContainer(webSocketClient, wsUrl);
  }

  @Bean
  WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter myWebSocketInboundChannelAdapter(
      final IntegrationWebSocketContainer myIntegrationWebSocketContainer,
      final MessageChannel myWebSocketOutputChannel,
      final MessageChannel myWebSocketErrorChannel) {
    final WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter adapter =
        new WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter(myIntegrationWebSocketContainer);
    adapter.setAutoStartup(false);
    adapter.setOutputChannel(myWebSocketOutputChannel);
    adapter.setErrorChannel(myWebSocketErrorChannel);
    return adapter;
  }

  @Bean
  IntegrationFlow myIntegrationFlow(
      final WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter myWebSocketInboundChannelAdapter,
      final MySocketHandler mySocketHandler,
      final MyOutputHandler myOutputHandler) {
    return IntegrationFlow.from(myWebSocketInboundChannelAdapter)
        .<String>handle(mySocketHandler)
        .<MyMessage>filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .handle(myOutputHandler)
        .get();
  }
}

@Component
public class MyWebSocketErrorHandler {
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "myWebSocketErrorChannel")
  public void handleError(final Message<?> message) {
    log.error("WebSocket error: {}", message.getPayload());
  }
}
```

I don´t see the custom error message in the log when I start this flow and the WS is not available, for instance. I just see the DeploymentException stack trace.

I have omitted MySocketHandler and MyOutputHandler implementations as they are simple GenericHandler classes.

### Edit 2

This is the exception stack trace when the websocket URL is not available when start is called:

> 2023-10-25T18:47:55.304Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8811-exec-1] c.m.r.i.flow.IntegrationFlowManager      : Starting integration flow MY
> 2023-10-25T18:47:55.304Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8811-exec-1] er$IntegrationWebSocketConnectionManager : Starting IntegrationWebSocketConnectionManager
> 2023-10-25T18:47:55.304Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8811-exec-1] er$IntegrationWebSocketConnectionManager : Connecting to WebSocket at wss://ws-simulator:3001/ws
> 2023-10-25T18:47:55.313Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8811-exec-1] o.s.i.w.i.WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter : started bean 'MY.websocket:inbound-channel-adapter#0'
> 2023-10-25T18:47:55.410Z ERROR 1 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] er$IntegrationWebSocketConnectionManager : Failed to connect

> jakarta.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the WebSocket connection to [wss://ws-simulator:3001/ws] failed
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServerRecursive(WsWebSocketContainer.java:429) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:179) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
> at org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient.lambda$executeInternal$0(StandardWebSocketClient.java:150) ~[spring-websocket-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
> at org.springframework.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$toSupplier$0(FutureUtils.java:74) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of stream
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperSecure$WrapperFuture.get(AsyncChannelWrapperSecure.java:492) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.processResponse(WsWebSocketContainer.java:793) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServerRecursive(WsWebSocketContainer.java:335) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.11.jar!/:na]
> ... 5 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of stream
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.AsyncChannelWrapperSecure$ReadTask.run(AsyncChannelWrapperSecure.java:261) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.11.jar!/:na]        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
> ... 1 common frames omitted

Comment: Since it's async, you'd never be able to do this. Not a Spring library I'm familiar with, but there's some configuration of whatever `flowId` is a reference to. With how Spring libraries typically work, you'd register some sort of error handler during configuration.

Comment: You need to show an example flow, and stack trace. Edit the question; don't try to put it in a comment.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the flow by itself. That `start()` is propagated down to endpoints registered in that flow, so indeed a check for "file exists" may happen on the other thread since a `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` does its work in a `TaskScheduler`.

Comment: @ArtemBilan you are correct, I have error handling in the flow, I need to react to errors that happen when starting the adapter, like trying a different directory or URL, for example.

Comment: I need to add resilience to the integration flows. My reasoning was to catch any exception in the adapter initialization, scrap the faulty flow, create a new flow with an alternative endpoint and start it. Repeat this as many times as needed until a config works.

Comment: Right. That's why Gary is asking you to show config of such a flow. You really can have an `errorChannel` on the inbound channel adapter and react to the `ErrorMessage` sent to that channel respectively.

Comment: I have added an example flow to give more context. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Hey, @ArtemBilan, does the new information added help to clarify the issue?

Comment: Yeah... I see. Unfortunately this `WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter` doesn't react properly to the `start()` failure of its `IntegrationWebSocketContainer`. Feel free to raise a GH issue and we will investigate. Thanks